# ansible read ip address from hosts

Tags: ansible

I need to set date to remote host, so I read localhost date then need to get the otherhost "ipv4_address" that is defined in hosts file of ansible.

```
- hosts: localhost
  become_user : root
  tasks:

    - name: align datetime
      shell: |
                 data="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d +%H:%m:00')"
                 ssh  user@{{ otherhost.ipv4_address }} "sudo date -s $data"

- hosts: otherhost
  become: true
his tasks....
```

but it seems that is not the correct way to get the ipv4:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
>   with an undefined variable. The error was: 'otherhost.ipv4_address ' is
>   undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.2
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/tec1/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/sniperx-EdPGXWMw/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/tec1/.local/share/virtualenvs/sniperx-EdPGXWMw/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `{{ otherhost.ipv4_address }}` is not available at the time you are using it as ansible hasnt gathered facts about `otherhost`.

A few options are available to you:

1. Gather facts before you start using the data, for example

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  # here you gather facts about otherhost

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars["otherhost"].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
      # and here you can access those facts about
```

2. Run the playbook at the remote host and delegate the localhost time before hand, for example

```
- hosts: otherhost
  tasks:
  - name: get localhost time
    shell: date +'%Y/%m/%d +%H:%m:00'
    become: false
    register: local_date
  - name: set the date on the server
    shell: sudo date -s '{{ local_date.stdout_lines[0] }}'
```

This takes advantage of ansibles way of auto-ssh-ing into the target box and you dont have to manual `ssh`.